# Static method to get method name

Tags: java, static

is there a good way to create a utils that we will call the name of the method in which it was used?

```
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
    public class NameUtils {
    
    public static String getMethodName(){
    ...
    }
    }
    
    public class MyClass {
    
    public void methodName(){
    
    String name = NameUtils.getMethodName()   //should return 'methodName'
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to get it from the stack trace which you can get via `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current stack trace from `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and analyse it to get the information you need.

Thanks to *user16320675* and *Holger* who pointed out that my initial solution was uneccessary complex.

Comment: really *schauderhaft* ;-)  better use [`Thread#getStackTrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace())  instead of throwing and catching an Exception

Comment: Why not analyze the stack trace right after you created the exception? Throwing and catching the exception does not add anything useful to the process. Of course, it’s even clearer when you call [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()). That method also does just `new Exception().getStackTrace()` under the hood, but using the method better documents the intention. Or use [`StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html) to only process *one* stack frame.